# TCL : How substitution occures in if statement

Tags: tcl

Consider this code where `a` is a global variable:

```
% set a 1
1
% # FirstCase 
% if "$a==1" "
       puts >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
"
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
% # Second case
% if {$a==1} {
     puts >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
}
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

In my first case, I made an `if` statement with `""`. Hence substitution of `a` will be done here. Acceptable.

In my second case, I made an `if` statement with `{}`. How does substitution of `a` happen here? `{}` means do not substitute and yet there is the variable being used. In the `if` related code, does it look for the global stack for variable `a`?

Answer (score 2):

The `if` command, like `expr` was designed to explicitly substitute the arguments given to it. Using `""` grouping is inadvisable because it may cause double substitution to occur.

Like other commands in tcl, `if` is actually a function. It doesn't look at the global stack but instead evaluates the expression in the caller's stack.

You can in fact write your own version of if using uplevel:

```
proc _if_ {expression script} {
    # uplevel causes expr to be evaluated in the caller's stack:
    set condition [uplevel 1 "expr {$expression}"]

    if {$condition} {
        uplevel 1 $script
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first case: "$a==1" is a string and not Zero Value, which will make it true: Try->

```
% if "0" "
 puts >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
"
```

It will not pass the condition. You got lucky here because "$a==1" has value not zero and value passed to if became true.

In second case:

```
% if {$a==1} {
    puts >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
}
```

$a==1 -> is a condition itself.

Comment: Sorry, but int tcl there is no difference between the string "0" and the value 0. Your understanding is wrong. The string "$a==1" is substituted into "1==1" before the `if` is called. The string "1==1" evaluates to true (technically, 1) so the puts gets executed. In the second case the string "\$a==1" is passed in directly and `if` then evaluates it in the calling stack which has access to $a so it also evaluates to true and the puts gets executed as well. Both works, his question is **why**?

Comment: i exactly meant the same. "$a==1" is treated like a string which will be evaluated and then will return the result 1 or 0. Thanks @slebetman for clarifying me.

Comment: The returned result 1 or 0 are also strings